# Why do I get the error 'list' object has no attribute 'update' when my for loop is too long?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

If I increase the number when the "for-loop" has to stop I get the error:  'list' object has no attribute 'update'. An example is: range(1000) instead of range(100).
That doesn't make any sense for me.
Could somebody help?
I need this code for school.
Here's the code:

```
import math  
import operator
 
m = 1.60
t = 2.4
 
x_1 = 2
x_2 = 3
x_3 = 5
y_1 = 6
y_2 = 8.9
y_3 = 11.5
 
dictionary_sum_f_m = {}
 
for i in range(1000):
 
    m += 0.1
    ###############################################
    y_Wert_th_1 = m * x_1 + best_t
    y_Wert_th_2 = m * x_2 + best_t
    y_Wert_th_3 = m * x_3 + best_t
 
    d_y_Wert_th_1 = y_Wert_th_1 - y_1
    d_y_Wert_th_2 = y_Wert_th_2 - y_2
    d_y_Wert_th_3 = y_Wert_th_3 - y_3
 
    f_1 = d_y_Wert_th_1 **2
    f_2 = d_y_Wert_th_2**2
    f_3 = d_y_Wert_th_3 **2
    sum_f_m = f_1 + f_2 + f_3
    ############################################
 
    dictionary_sum_f_m.update({m : sum_f_m})
    if i == 99:
       dictionary_sum_f_m= sorted(dictionary_sum_f_m.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) 
       sorted_dictionary_sum_f_m = dict(dictionary_sum_f_m)
       best_m = list(sorted_dictionary_sum_f_m.keys())[0]
       print(best_m)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the length of your loop, and everything to do with the fact that you apparently assigned a `list` to a name that used to (and is supposed to) refer to a `dict`.

Comment: If you hit `i==99` you reset `dictionary_sum_f_m` to a list. Also, `best_t` is undefined and your code will not run for any range large or small

Answer (score 0):

When `i == 99`, you convert `dictionary_sum_f_m` to a sorted `list` and never convert it back to a `dict`. `dict`s provide `.update`, `list`s don't. You don't actually need it to be a `list` anyway (you're looking for the key with the smallest value, and the rest of the sorting is unnecessary), so you could solve the problem with just:

```
if i == 99:
   best_m, best_val = min(dictionary_sum_f_m.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) 
   print(best_m)
```

which leaves `dictionary_sum_f_m` untouched, and reduces `O(n log n)` sort work to just `O(n)` work to retrieve the minimum value.

Side-notes:

1. Your code reads from `best_t` but I don't see it defined; guessing you made a copy-and-paste error and omitted it, since you'd never reach the point where you saw the failure as written.
2. This

   ```
   dictionary_sum_f_m.update({m : sum_f_m})
   ```

   is an unnecessarily slow way to spell:

   ```
   dictionary_sum_f_m[m] = sum_f_m
   ```

   `update` is for *bulk* updates, usually with existing `dict`s; if you're making a one-item `dict` just to call `update`, you should stick to simple key assignment.